# Tooling API usage in salesforce Apex method

Tags: tooling-api

I am trying all my level best to know how the Tooling API is used. Can someone suggest or show me with a small example on how do I create a apexClass in a controller method.

I have already generated metadataservice from WSDL.

Comment: https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/force-tooling-demo             following uses REST API and java and may be easier than using SOAP .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I prefer the REST flavor of the Tooling API. Here's a sample method to create a class:

```
// Class variable for Tooling API base URL
// you'll need to add the base URL as a Remote Site in the org
private static String baseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() 
    + '/services/data/v28.0/tooling/';

public static void createClass() {
    // Note the escaping on newlines and quotes
    String classBody = 'public class MyNewClass {\\n'
        + ' public string SayHello() {\\n'
        + '  return \'Hello\';\\n' 
        + ' }\\n'
        + '}';

    HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(baseUrl + 'sobjects/ApexClass');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    // OAuth header
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setBody('{'+
        '"Body" : "' + classBody +'"'+
    '}');

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    // Response to a create should be 201
    if (res.getStatusCode() != 201) {
        System.debug(res.getBody());
        throw new MyException(res.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @meatadaddy. That helped me to understand the basics on tooling API.

Comment: can some one show me usage of SOAP API for the same. I am not getting any push on how to proceed on the Tooling API SOAP flavour. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @metadaddy..If i try to create a apex class by using 
String sampleClass = 'MyNewClass';

String classBody = 'public class ' + sampleClass + ' {\\n' 
            + ' public ' + sampleClass + ' {\\n'
            + '\\n' 
            + ' }\\n'
            + '}';
it doesn't work. Throws an SOAP error INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE"..How can i achieve something like that.

Comment: @ForceDeveloper Ask a new question with more code - it's hard to see what the problem is from one line.

Comment: @metadaddy Thanks for kind words..Posted a question and got the answer also