# Dynamic Apex Class

Tags: rest-api, tooling-api

I am using Tooling API to create a class. Used the following [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15843/tooling-api-usage-in-salesforce-apex-method) as reference to create  a class and it works fine. But if i try to make it bit more dynamic by putting Apex Class Name in string and using it in the Body it doesn't work. I am getting following Error : "unexpected token: 'MyNewClass'","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE".

**EDIT

Following is the code snippet which i ran from the developer console.

```
String salesforceHost = System.Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();

String url =  salesforceHost + '/services/data/v28.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass';

String sampleClass = 'MyNewClass';

String classBody = 'public class ' + sampleClass + ' {\\n' 
        + ' public ' + sampleClass + ' {\\n'
        + '\\n' 
        + ' }\\n'
        + '}';


HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());        
req.setBody('{'+
    '"Body" : "' + classBody +'"'+
 '}');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
String resBody = res.getBody();
```

Note : if i change the first two lines of classBody it will work i.e.

```
String classBody = 'public class MyNewClass {\\n' 
        + ' public MyNewClass {\\n'
```

Did i miss anything?

**UPDATE**

Use Double Back Slash by default since it works all the time. if you want to format the body contents by providing space then single slash may not work at times.

Thanks

Comment: I just tried and it works just fine. Can you post you full code that you're using? Also, make sure that a class by the name `MyNewClass` doesn't exist before executing this code? Even if it does it should give a `DUPLICATE_VALUE` errorCode and not the above one..

Comment: @theGreatDanton Hi..Thanks for the reply...i edited the question also the class is not present in the org...Also i tried this in multiple orgs and its not working

Comment: Change the authorization header from OAuth to Bearer and try again. It should look something like this : `req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found two problems with your dynamically constructed Apex code which I have addressed below.

- You only need one back slash to inject the carriage return character into the code
- You had not declared the class constructor correctly, it needed the braces ()

After i made these changes and applied to my Apex Tooling API code below it worked.

```
// Create the ApexClass via Tooling REST API
String sampleClass = 'MyNewClass';
String classBody = 'public class ' + sampleClass + ' {\n' 
        + ' public ' + sampleClass + '() {\n'
        + '\n' 
        + ' }\n'
        + '}';
JSONGenerator body = JSON.createGenerator(false);
body.writeStartObject();
body.writeStringField('Name', sampleClass);
body.writeStringField('Body', classBody);
body.writeEndObject();
HttpRequest createReq = new HttpRequest();
createReq.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v29.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass');
createReq.setBody( body.getAsString() );
createReq.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
createReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
createReq.setMethod('POST');
Http h = new Http();    
HttpResponse createRes = h.send(createReq);
```

Comment: Wow ..@andrew you're awesome...That constructor stuff was typo...Thanks for pointing it out...Its working as expected but i thought i need to escape the backslash when i embed it in string?

Comment: It works even with the double back slash...I totally messed it up by missing the constructor syntax...thanks

Comment: Ha no worries, you do need the back slash, the double back slash is to escape the back slash, i suspect it works either way because the API unescapes again internally.

Comment: Good Work Andrew ..