# Bulkify the Tooling/Metadata API

Tags: apex, rest-api, metadata-api, tooling-api

Came across various articles and I **couldn't** find approach for bulkyfying the Tooling/metadata API. In this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15843/tooling-api-usage-in-salesforce-apex-method), the most voted answer handles one request at a time. However what I am trying to achieve is, There are 100+ Outbound Messages(OBMs) in my org and would like to update the endpoint URL of them using tooling API ( basically schedule a class or something later). I do know how I can hit using rest Explorer/workbench/or even from apex with the help of above great post. But again I know how to handle 1 request at a time. All I can think of now is **invoke the httpRequest in a for loop for each OBM**. So Is my approach OK or any better solutions/suggestions pls ?

Answer (score 2):

100+ from off platform if you are doing that should be fine .

If you are using apex callout , then a single context allows only 100 callouts , so you might want to do this in a batch apex with a batch size of 50 .