# SOQL query for the "Where is this used?" button for a particular field

Tags: soql

I am looking for a SOQL query that can display where a particular field is being referenced in Salesforce. Salesforce already has a button called "Where is this used?" for custom fields that displays all the field references. How would I write that function as a SOQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to the previous post here is the sample query you can run in Developer Console with 'Use Tooling API' enabled in Query Editor.

```
SELECT MetadataComponentType, MetadataComponentName, RefMetadataComponentName, RefMetadataComponentId
FROM MetadataComponentDependency
WHERE RefMetadataComponentId = 'fieldId' AND RefMetadataComponentType = 'CustomField'
ORDER By RefMetadataComponentName
```

You need some way of getting FieldId though to filter by `RefMetadataComponentId`.

In SOQL you can't execute it because it doesn't support `ToolingApi`. In order to do so you need to do HttpRequest to `Tooling API`.

As an example you can use this post [Tooling API usage in salesforce Apex method](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15843/tooling-api-usage-in-salesforce-apex-method)

Here is a link to documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resources.htm

Use this endpoint `/services/data/${API_VERSION}/tooling/query/?q=`

**UPDATE**
thanks Jeff for the Field Query.

You can use this field to get Id for particular field

```
SELECT Id 
FROM CustomField 
WHERE FullName = 'Object_Api_Name__c.Field_Api_Name__c'
```

Comment: If you are looking for references to a Custom Field, you can use the same Tooling API to query the CustomField object to get the Id reference you'll find in the RefMetadataComponentId and MetadataComponentId fields for CustomFields: 

select Id from CustomField where FullName = 'Object_Api_Name__c.Field_Api_Name__c'

Comment: thanks, I'll update the answer

Comment: Thank you, this was really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the object you are looking to query is: [MetadataComponentDependency](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm)

This is most likely what Salesforce uses behind the scenes with the 'Where is this used?' button. I have not tested this, but according to the documentation you should be able to call this using the Tooling API or Bulk API 2.0

Please note, it says that this is currently a feature in **Beta** so usage may be limited.

Here is a link to the [Dependency API/Field Usage chatter group](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A00000020Vu)

If you read through the posts, you can probably get a better idea of how to query and what works / doesnt.

Hope that helps and is what you were looking for!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right, Salesforce does use MetadataComponentDependency in Tooling API for this.