# Salesforce query for working in code for testing

Tags: soql, query, soap-api, tooling-api

Below is the query i want to run without using tooling api is there a way possible if not how to use tooling api in my code as i Have never used it in code apart from dev console.

```
SELECT  QualifiedApiName FROM EntityDefinition where QualifiedApiName = 'objectname' AND IsFieldHistoryTracked = true AND IsReportingEnabled = true AND IsSearchable = true
```

Comment: Check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15843/tooling-api-usage-in-salesforce-apex-method