# Check if feature test run was enabled

Tags: apex, release-update

In Salesforce, under Setup => Release Updates, there are options to enable test runs for various features. Is there a way to determine in Apex if a specific feature has been enabled? Specifically, I'm interested in finding out if the user has enabled the test run for [Enable Lightning Article Editor and Article Personalization for Knowledge](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_knowledge_release_update.htm&language=en_US&release=244&type=5) (Beta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Tooling API and query [ReleaseUpdate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_releaseupdate.htm).

> SupportsRevoke
>
> Type boolean Properties:  Defaulted on create, Filter, Group, Sort
>
> Description:  Indicates if the update has a test run(true) or not (false). Default is false.

Tooling API SOQL:

```
SELECT SupportsRevoke,status,ReleaseLabel FROM ReleaseUpdate where Title='Enable Lightning Article Editor and Article Personalization for Knowledge (Beta)'
```

See more on [Tooling API usage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15843/tooling-api-usage-in-salesforce-apex-method) in salesforce Apex method